# React Native ScrollView with absolutely positioned children relative to screen size

Tags: css, react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal ScrollView component wrapping the whole screen in React Native, with its first child being an image that takes up the full device height, and extends past the device width. I am trying to absolutely position elements within the background image so that they are always in the same relative position to the background on different devices, and I can not figure out how. Any help would be SUPER appreciated.

Current code example:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView horizontal={true} bounces={false}>
    <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage}>
      <Element style={{position: "absolute", top: "30%", left: "50%"}}>
    </ImageBackground>
  </ScrollView>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: SCREEN.height,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    height: SCREEN.height,
    width: SCREEN.height * 1.125,
  },
})
```

The issue is that the elements which have an absolute positioning end up in different places against the background image on different devices. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `<ImageBackground />` class. As per React-Native documentation, the image fits the entire available space without losing the width to height ratio of the original image, which causes the image to scale and in this case, the developer has on control over the scaling factor.

```
<Element style={{position: "absolute", top: "30%", left: "50%"}}>
```

For the above **Element** class,you can only position it wrt the screen's width and height while using **%** and `position: absolute`.

To summarize, your code for Elements class styling is perfect, the issue is with  the `<ImageBackground />` class.

Also all device have different aspect ratio, hence using this:

```
    width: SCREEN.height * 1.125,
```

might not be the best option.

You could do something like this instead:

```
import {View, ScrollView, Dimension} from react-native;
const {width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');

<View style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView horizontal={true} bounces={false}>
      <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage}>
         <Element style={{position: "absolute", top: "30%", left: "50%"}}>
      </ImageBackground>
   </ScrollView>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    height: viewportHeight,
    width: viewportWidth,
  },
})
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Cheers mate!

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response Gavin. The problem is that the Background Image needs to be longer than the screen width by a significant amount, hence the need for a horizontal ScrollView. The 1.125 added to the image accounts for its own ratio, not the screen's.

Comment: @ahrampy I think I understand  the issue and have a solution to it as well, but just need to confirm if we're on the same page. Can you share screenshots of the excepted ui and the actual ui that you are getting on your device?